# Get a nexus artifact as a dependency in gradle?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the following nexus artifact :

```
com/companyName/my-awesome-util/0.0.0/my-awesome-util-0.0.0.jar
```

and I just have absolutely no clue how to get it within my gradle build file. I have googled it, followed examples, and I just cannot get it to work. I come from the maven world, and I just need to get this one thing to work so that I can at least understand what the hell I need to do in future.

Comment: It's all explained in the manual: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 9):

First, add a repository in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://nexus.acme.corp' }
}
```

Then, refer to that artifact:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.companyName:my-awesome-util:0.0.0'
}
```

That's basically it!

If your Nexus is [secured](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository:credentials(org.gradle.api.Action)) by credentials, use this snippet:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://nexus.acme.corp'

        credentials {
            username = 'darth'
            password = 'vader'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for taking forever to reply, by any chance do you know how I would also make this work with nexus credentials?

Comment: When I do that - I get this error : > Could not get unknown property 'nexusUsername' for object of type org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer.

Have you seen that before?

Comment: Ah wait - I got that to work by passing in the nexus username and password - but it seems as though gradle cannot resolve my dependency... I am getting this now : 

Could not resolve: com.companyName:my-awesome-util:0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Add some Nexus `maven2 proxy` repositories with the following remote storage urls each:

```
https://jcenter.bintray.com/
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
https://maven.google.com/    # used to download com.android.tools.build:gradle
https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/
```

And then add them into a `meven2 group` repository, named such as `maven-public`:

[image]

And then use this group repo's url in your file `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    //        jcenter()
    maven {
    //            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    url "https://YOUR-NEXUS-URL.com/repository/maven-public/"


        }
    }

 ......
........
......
allprojects {

repositories {
buildscript {

    apply from: 'dependencies.gradle'

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
//        jcenter()
        maven {
//            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
            url "https://YOUR-NEXUS-URL.com/repository/maven-public/"

        }
    }
}
}
```